# Why do I not get two legends using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting different models' prediction lines over some data points. I would like to get a legend indicating to which individual belongs each point colour and another legend indicating to which model belongs each line colour. Below I share a fake example for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Height =rnorm(500, mean=175, sd=15),
                 Weight =rnorm(500, mean=70, sd=20),
                 ID = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), (500/4)))

mod1 <- lmer(Height ~ Weight + (1|ID), df)
mod2 <- lmer(Height ~ poly(Weight,2) + (1|ID), df)

y.mod1 <- predict(mod1, data.frame(Weight=df$Weight),re.form=NA) # Prediction of y according to model 1
y.mod2 <- predict(mod2, data.frame(Weight=df$Weight),re.form=NA) # Prediction of y according to model 2

df <- cbind(df, y.mod1,y.mod2)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

head(df)

    Height   Weight ID   y.mod1   y.mod2
1 166.5929 57.96214  A 175.9819 175.4918
2 171.5473 50.12603  B 176.2844 176.3003
3 198.3806 90.53570  C 174.7241 174.7082
4 176.0576 85.02123  D 174.9371 174.5487
5 176.9393 39.81667  A 176.6825 177.7303
6 200.7260 68.09705  B 175.5905 174.8027
```

First I plot my data points:

```
Plot_a <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Weight, y=Height,colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))

Plot_a
```

[image]

Then, I add lines relative to the prediction models:

```
Plot_b <- Plot_a + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod1,color='mod1'),show.legend = T) + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod2,color='mod2'),show.legend = T) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)),
         color=guide_legend(title=c("Model")))

Plot_b
```

[image]

Does anyone know why I am not getting two different legends, one titled `Model` and the other `ID`?

I would like to get this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that in ggplot2 each aesthetic can only have one scale and only one legend. As you are using only the `color` aes you get one legend. If you want multiple legends for the same aesthetic have a look at the `ggnewscales` package. Otherwise you have to make use of a second aesthetic.

My preferred approach would be similar to the one proposed by @RuiBarradas. However, to stick close to your approach this could be achieved like so:

1. Instead of color map on `linetype` in your calls to `geom_line`.
2. Set the colors for the lines as arguments, i.e. not inside aes.
3. Make use of `scale_linetype_manual` to get solid lines for both models.
4. Make use of `guide_legend` to fix the colors appearing in the legend

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Height =rnorm(500, mean=175, sd=15),
                 Weight =rnorm(500, mean=70, sd=20),
                 ID = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), (500/4)))

mod1 <- lmer(Height ~ Weight + (1|ID), df)
mod2 <- lmer(Height ~ poly(Weight,2) + (1|ID), df)

y.mod1 <- predict(mod1, data.frame(Weight=df$Weight),re.form=NA) # Prediction of y according to model 1
y.mod2 <- predict(mod2, data.frame(Weight=df$Weight),re.form=NA) # Prediction of y according to model 2

df <- cbind(df, y.mod1,y.mod2)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
Plot_a <- ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Weight, y=Height, colour=ID)) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))

line_colors <- scales::hue_pal()(2)
Plot_b <- Plot_a + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod1, linetype = "mod1"), color = line_colors[1]) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod2, linetype = "mod2"), color = line_colors[2]) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(mod1 = "solid", mod2 = "solid")) +
  labs(color = "ID", linetype = "Model") +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = line_colors)))

Plot_b
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @stefan, one (silly) doubt. If I want to name to the lines as `X¹` and `X²`, how should I do? I mean, If I change in your code `linetype = "mod1"` by `linetype = "X¹"`, then, I have to change `mod1 = "solid"` by `X¹ = "solid"`, but this last is not allowed. I can't use `X¹` without `""`. How could I solve this?

Comment: The easiest approach to achieve this is by setting the labels inside `scale_linetype_manual` using the labels argument, i.e. `labels = c(mod1 = bquote(~X^1), mod2 = bquote(~X^2))`

Answer (score 6):

This type of problems generaly has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from long to wide format.

The plot layers become simpler, one `geom_line` is enough and there is no need for `guide`to override the aesthetics.

To customize the models' legend text, create a vector of legends, in this case with [`plotmath`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html), in order to have math notation. And the colors are set manually too.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

model_labels <- c(expression(X^1), expression(X^2))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(y.mod1, y.mod2),
    names_to = "Model",
    values_to = "Value"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Weight, Height)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = ID), shape = 21) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Value, color = Model)) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = model_labels, 
                     values = c("coral", "coral4")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: @Thanks Rui, can I ask you something? If I want to change names `y.mod1` and `y.mod2` to `X¹` and `X²`, should I change variables name in the beginning? Additionally, I have 5 lines in my real case, so I think the best will be to customize the colour of the lines. Do I do this with `scale_color_manual()`? Thanks for your time again.

Comment: @Dekike Yes, that should be done with `scale_color_manual`. See the edit. The new colors are just an example.